# Get server IP of PPP VPN in Windows using VBScript or CMD

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, vpn, ppp

Is it possible to use VBScript or commandline to grab the server IP of a PPP VPN under Windows?

[image]

Note this is not VPN dialup server IP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBScript to get the information from WMI. There are plenty of networking scripts [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394595%28VS.85%29.aspx).
For example, use the following script to get the IP of a given net adapter. Just be sure to provide your VPN's name instead of the "Local Area Connection 2" string:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject(_
    "winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapter " _
        & "Where NetConnectionID = " & _
        "'Local Area Connection 2'")

For Each objItem in colItems
    strMACAddress = objItem.MACAddress
Next

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")

For Each objItem in colItems
    If objItem.MACAddress = strMACAddress Then
        For Each strIPAddress in objItem.IPAddress
            Wscript.Echo "IP Address: " &  strIPAddress
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thank you, but the server IP as shown in the image is dynamically assigned, and looks like it can not be retrieved from WMI.

Comment: This code retrieves the current IP, as in "dynamically assigned". Did you try it? If it doesn't work, there are a couple of other WMI classes you could try - see the article.

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy,

Yes your script got the client IP, but not the server IP.